# Spring Boot log file relative to jar directory not start directory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot configuration file, can I specify a logging file location relative to the Spring Boot jar instead of relative to the directory the jar is started from?

Example:

```
#application.yml
logging:
  file: ./logs/app.log
```

Directories:

- /app/dir/app.jar
- /random/dir

Start:

```
cd /random/dir
java -jar /app/dir/app.jar
```

Result:

- /random/dir/logs/app.log

Desired:

- /app/dir/logs/app.log

Additional Info:
The jar will be running on different operating systems. So the jar path could be similar to:

- /app/dir/app.jar
- C:\app\dir\app.jar

At run time, I can calculate what the jar/install directory is.  Is there a Java solution that would allow me to set the logging.file location after startup?  Or is the logger already initialized at that point?

Complete Solution:  based on @satyesht

```
#application.yml

app:
  log:
    #Set a default directory in case a user "double clicks" the jar to launch it.
    dir: ./logs
    file: app.log

logging:
  file: ${app.log.dir}/${app.log.file}
```

Start:

```
cd /random/dir
java -Dapp.log.dir=/app/dir/logs -jar /app/dir/app.jar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way would be to pass the log directory as a system property as below .

```
#application.yml
logging:
  file: ${LOGDIR}/logs/app.log
```

and while running your application you can specify the LOGDIR system property as a VM argument

```
cd /random/dir
java -jar /app/dir/app.jar -DLOGDIR=/app/dir/
```

Comment: java -DLOGDIR=/app/dir -jar /app/dir/app.jar

Answer (score 0):

You would have to know the location of the jarfile ahead of time. But yes, the difference is between [absolute, and relative paths](https://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/).

Using `.` indicates that you want to start from the location where our console window is open. This is a path that is **relative** to the location you are in the terminal.

Using / indicates that you want to start at the root of the drive. Now, obviousally you don't want to store the file in the root of the drive. But let's say i Had my jar in the folder: `/app/dir/app.jar` Then configuration is as simple as saying:

```
#application.yml
logging:
  file: /app/dir/logs/app.log
```

Comment: Thanks, I added "Addition Info" to my original post to clarify that the jar will be running on different OS's at different paths.  So an absolute path isn't an option.  Unless I can do an OS conditional variable in the yaml/properties file.